# How to find the dynamic central points of an image in matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-figure

I have a matrix named [**`original`**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07029772265620838132) and the respective plot is shown in the image below.

[image: **Main Figure**]

I would like to however get the *center portion* of the image in the form of respective rows into another variable as highlighted approximately in the next figure.

[image: Center extraction]

I looked up to find the center and got to know of the method of using `centroid` in `regionprops`. For example like the code sample below.

```
s = regionprops(original,'centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2), 'b*')
```

This method of using `centroid` did not help me to obtain the entire central rows. Is there any alternative way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by center portion of the image ?

Comment: The center is dynamic. For example at x=600 the image is a bit pinched. I want the center to adopt to the wavy plot in my figure and I want to extract this. (Not a single straight center line in the middle).

Comment: So you want the center of the yellow region in every column of the image ?

Comment: Exactly. In the last columns, (Between row 170~190 approximately) there is some noise above the desired region. This must not be taken and can be removed if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compute the average non-zero index in each column would be to directly compute it.

Edit: It's not clear what is meant by noise, but if I interpret this as you want to only consider the widest region per column then we can find the average of this region as follows.

```
avg = zeros(1,size(original,2));
for c = 1:size(original,2)
    % find largest contiguous region in the column
    sig = original(:,c);
    der = diff([false; sig; false]);
    upedge = find(der == 1);
    downedge = find(der == -1);
    [~,region_idx] = max(downedge-upedge);
    first = upedge(region_idx);
    last = downedge(region_idx)-1;

    % get the average index in the region
    avg(c) = (last + first) / 2;
end

% plot results
hold off;
imagesc(original); hold on;
plot(1:size(original,2), avg, '-r', 'LineWidth', 2);
set(gca, 'YDir', 'normal');
axis([1, size(original,2), 1, 250]);
```

Which, results in the following figure

[image]

Comment: Yes. I wanted only the continuous part to be selected as there were other tit bit pieces in the columns of my other images. Very informative and helpful. Thanks. I would like more comments (what exactly is done in those steps) in the above code for finding the largest continuous region as I didn't understand that part.

Comment: I loop through each column of the image. To find the largest region I find where the signal goes from `false` to `true` and `true` to `false` using `diff`. Because I pad the image with `false` I'm guaranteed to have one up transition for every down transition. I find the indices of those transition and take the pair which span the largest duration.